# adding subdomain to localhost expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on expressjs application. locally my application run on 
http://localhost:3000, I want to run this application on http://localhost.mycomp.com as well.

is it possible to achieve this without editing /etc/hosts/ file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using /etc/hosts it would be possible only if the DNS for `mycomp.com` would have 127.0.0.1 in the `A` record of the `localhost.mycomp.com` subdomain - which is unlikely as that would be very insecure.

Other than that you could run a local name resolver that does that but this is basically just like using /etc/hosts but harder. Or you could route IP traffic for the IP that `localhost.mycomp.com` resolves to (if it exists) to your own loopback or other local interface but that would be even harder.